# Need to send multiple PUT request through JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Expecting to send multiple PUT requests through JMeter to test PUT API with below mentioned constraints:

> 1. Multiple logged in users.
> 2. Multiple users with different data to be updated.

Looking forward to get the help in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create scripts in Jmeter if you want to send multiple PUT requests. You have to create PUT request in Jmeter using HTTP sampler.

**Multiple logged in users.**

- If the APIs that you are testing uses some authentication mechanism (which i reckon it should), then you have to add other HTTP requests(Authentication requests) as part of Jmeter test. Otherwise, you can increase the number of users in the thread group and do testing.

**Multiple users with different data to be updated.**

- For this task - you have to parametrize the PUT request data. You can go through google and learn about parametrization in Jmeter.

I would suggest you to first explore Jmeter, learn some basics of performance testing and then go ahead with testing.